# Move reCAPTCHA (V2) Image validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, recaptcha

I have a reCaptcha (Version 2) inside a  which is position fixed to the bottom of the page. When I click the "I'm not a robot button" inside the reCaptcha the image validation div shows up to the left of the reCaptcha, however, it is cut off at the bottom and at times the "Verify" button is cut off.

Here is what I have tried:

- I've looked into callbacks but googles 'callback' only gets triggered upon a successful validation which is too late.
- I've tried setting a new "top" value for the image validation form. This is difficult because it does not have a class or id and appears in different places on each page. (and even when it does work it doesn't scale)

Are there any ways to move the image validation so it does not get cut off? Thanks!